# javascript onclick function variable undefined

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a javascrpt onclick function but it is saying variables are undefined, the onclick is from an  tag

```
<a href="#" title="Click to select" rowno="'+NROW+'" name="'+NAME+'" onClick="remname(rowno,name);"></a>
```

i get an error saying 'rowno' is undefined

This however only happens in IE11 IE7 works perfectly and will run the function

javascript :

```
    function remname(NAME,ROW)
{
    if (confirm('Remove registration entry '+NAME+'?'))
    {
        ***FUNCTION USING ANOTHER SYSTEM***
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the definition of `remname(rowno,name)` too..also if you could reproduce the issue in a fiddle, it would be helpful..

Comment: You can't just add your own attribute like this. try using data-* instead. (Which solves half of the problem. Later make remname accept dom element  , and there(!) read those attributes)

Comment: Again: Where is your Javascript code?

Comment: If possible, post both your HTML and Javascript codes. We will help you, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code part that is written in **onclick** attribute runs in a function where **this** references to the element which onclick attribute belongs to. Any other non global variable (in your case *rowno* and *name*) will be undefined.  Therefore, you can use `this` reference to access DOMElement which has method named `getAttrubute()` to fetch attributes value like so:

```
remname(this.getAttribute('rowno'), this.getAttribute('name'))
```

---

However, I also would suggest to use event listeners instead of on* attributes. That would be a better and easier to maintain practice.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="magicAnchor" title="Click to select" rowno="'+NROW+'" name="'+NAME+'"></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('magicAnchor').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (confirm('Remove registration entry '+ this.getAttribute('name') +'?'))
    {
        ***FUNCTION USING ANOTHER SYSTEM***
        // to access rowno attribute use: this.getAttribute('rowno')
    }
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Edited the code to have this.getAttribue and it now works

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing those variables you can access them later in remname() function like

```
var remname=function(){
            var rowno=document.getElementById("selectme").getAttribute("data-rowno");
            var NAME=document.getElementById("selectme").getAttribute("data-name");
            console.log(rowno+' '+NAME);
        }
```

and here is html

```
<a href="#" id="selectme" title="Click to select" data-rowno="'+NROW+'" data-name="'+NAME+'" onclick="remname()">abc</a>
```