# object didnt get passed to another method (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, methods

I currently learning react and following a Video tutorial, and I get stuck with an object that can't be passed to another method but when i passed an ID it works fine

here's the method

```
handleIncrement = (product) => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });   
};
```

and this is the method I try to pass on

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement({ id: 1 })}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
```

the product on `onClick={this.handleIncrement(product)}` error as undefined

```
src\components\counter.jsx
  Line 19:47:  'product' is not defined  no-undef
```

but if i use `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement({ id:1 })}` it working just fine, and also work when i use `onClick={(product) => this.handleIncrement(product)}`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I think this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499916/javascript-onclick-function-variable-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is with

```js
onClick={this.handleIncrement({ id: 1 })}
```

This is the usual confusion to newbie in ReactJS but here is the general rule of thumb, you have two ways

1. If your function is not expecting `parameter`

```js
funcWithoutParam = () => {
  console.log('hi')
}; 
onClick={this.funcWithoutParam}
```

2. If your function is expecting `parameter`

```js
handleIncrement = (param) => {
  console.log(param)
}

onClick={() => this.handleIncrement({ id: 1 })}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` event handler must be a function, not a function call. That's why the example you provided `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement({ id:1 })}` works as this is an anonymous function, while the example where you are calling the function does not work.